# Compiling Pharo to C?

Tags: compilation, smalltalk, pharo

It is said that Pharo's VM (CogVM) is developed, tested, profiled and etc in Smalltalk, but then the Smalltalk code is transcompiled to C, which is then compiled along side with some OS abstraction C code using the default system C compiler.

Well, I'd like to do a similar thing, I wan't to develop, test and profile code using Pharo, but then compile it to C. How can I do it? How the compilation to C works? Does Pharo comes with a Smalltalk to C transcompiler? How can I invoke it? Does it compile the full Smalltalk, or I have to use some kind of a Smalltalk subset? Is there any good documentation about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Pharo VM is [hosted on github](https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo-vm).
Follow the steps to build it and you'll get a Smalltalk image called "generator.image" which you can run (it's a regular image). Inside of that image you'll find the VMMaker package which is responsible for generating the C code from the special Smalltalk dialect used for this (which is called Slang; it's a subset of Smalltalk). Look at the code in the generator image to get a feel for what it does. There's also some information contained in the workspaces that are open when you first open the image.

As soon as you have the C sources it's basically straight forward C compilation (which we do with Cmake + gcc / clang).

As for documentation: you should probably read the [Blue Book](http://www.amazon.de/Smalltalk-80-Language-Implementation-Adele-Goldberg/dp/0201113716/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1426003922&sr=8-4&keywords=adele%20goldberg).

#### clarifiation

As @Leandro Caniglia points out in the comment, the purpose of Slang is to generate C source code for the VM. It has been designed to ease translation to C. That **does not** mean that:

- arbitrary Smalltalk code can be translated to C using the generating mechanism
- arbitrary Smalltalk code can be rewritten in Slang (at least not "easily")

Comment: I think we should add some clarification regarding the fact that Slang is not meant to provide support for translating a Smalltalk program into a C program, right? Otherwise, readers of this question could mistakenly interpret that there is a fairly straightforward way to do that. The expressiveness of Slang is sufficient for the generation of VM sources, but that doesn't mean that it suffices the generation of arbitrary Smalltalk code or that arbitrary Smalltalk code can be rewritten in terms of Slang.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

> I wan't to develop, test and profile code using Pharo, but then
> compile it to C.

- How can I do it?

Smalltalk code in Pharo will be compiled to bytecodes that the VM runs, so there is no way really to transpile straight Smalltalk code from Pharo to the raw metal via C.

- How the compilation to C works?

I've covered what in what I think is a friendly how-to here

[How to Create a Pharo Smalltalk Plugin -
From zero to hero, build a HelloWorldPlugin on Pharo 9](https://blog.sebastiansastre.co/article/how-to-create-a-pharo-smalltalk-plugin)

- Does Pharo comes with a Smalltalk to C transcompiler?

No, but it comes with a C sources generation framework to build the VM and its plugins and its corresponding Makefiles to build the artifacts.

- How can I invoke it?

If you take a look at the readme in this repo you'll have a better overall view and the steps to use it https://github.com/sebastianconcept/PharoPluginBuilder

- Does it compile the full Smalltalk, or I have to use some kind of a Smalltalk subset?

The normal way to do it would be to create the VM and its plugins.

- Is there any good documentation about it?

The Blue Book is a classic masterpiece. For Pharo specific docs, I've tried to cover the minimum in a practical way here: [A Simplified Guide to Creating a Pharo Smalltalk Plugin - Learn How to Build Your Own Plugin with StarterPlugin and PharoPluginBuilder](https://blog.sebastiansastre.co/article/a-simplified-guide-to-creating-a-pharo-smalltalk-plugin).